# how to create a picturebox in vb 2008 and move it?

Tags: vb.net, events, addition, picturebox

I just want to ask a really important question in vb2008 :
I'm working on 2D level designer that I just put all the images and the collision rectangles in his place then the program generate the right code.
the problem is : I make a button and in his click event it add a new picture box , when it add I have to move it with the mouse , I have the "move" code but like you know it's a new picture box so I can't write the code before the picture box add.(if you doesn't understand I can explain my situation again)

for more clear this is the code :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim i As Integer

    newPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ground.bmp")
    newPictureBox.Name = "image" & (i)
    newPictureBox.Visible = True
    newPictureBox.Top = 200
    newPictureBox.Width = 100
    newPictureBox.Height = 50
    newPictureBox.Left = 100 + goToRight
    newPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
    'add control to form
    Controls.Add(newPictureBox)
    goToRight = goToRight + newPictureBox.Width
    i += 1
End Sub
```

and this is the "move picturebox" code(it's for an existed picturbox):

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim endPoint As Integer = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Label1.Text = "X: " & MousePosition.X - (Location.X + 8)
    Label2.Text = "Y: " & MousePosition.Y - (Location.Y + 29)
    RadioButton1.Left = endPoint + RadioButton2.Left
    Panel1.Left = 0

    'Move picture code :
    If IcanMove = True Then

        PictureBox1.Left = MousePosition.X - (Location.X + 8) - differenceX
        PictureBox1.Top = MousePosition.Y - (Location.Y + 29) - differenceY
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    IcanMove = True
    differenceX = (MousePosition.X - (Location.X + 8)) - PictureBox1.Left
    differenceY = (MousePosition.Y - (Location.Y + 29)) - PictureBox1.Top
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    IcanMove = False
End Sub
```

thanks you for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add event handlers for the newly added `PictureBox`, here is how to do that.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim NewPictureBox As PictureBox = New PictureBox
    NewPictureBox.Parent = Me
    NewPictureBox.Location = New Point(100, 100)
    Me.Controls.Add(NewPictureBox)
    'you can use existing event handlers like your PictureBox1_MouseDown
    AddHandler NewPictureBox.MouseUp, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseUp
    AddHandler NewPictureBox.MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseDown
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Triggered MouseDown Event")
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Triggered MouseUp Event")
End Sub
```

(if you also remove the `PictureBox`'s before closing the form be sure to remove the handlers for them)
For more info check [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) and [RemoveHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xz97kac.aspx)